# Sharing cookies with popup window in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, cookies, casperjs

I have a CasperJS project that requires a new window (opened when clicking the "#view_item" button) to have access to the cookies and session of the parent window. Currently, the new window displays an error because it thinks there is no user logged in.

```
this.click("#view_item");

this.waitForPopup(/.+/, function() {
    this.capture("parent_window.jpg");
});

this.withPopup(/.+/, function()
{
    // Delay for testing
    this.wait(2000);
    this.capture("new_window.jpg");
});
```

Is there anything I can do short of dumping the cookies to a file before opening the window, loading them in the popup and refreshing the page?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to overwrite the cookies from the parent window (this is only a bit shorter than to write it to a file).

```
var cookie = this.evaluate(function(){
    return window.document.cookie; // just a string
});

this.click("#view_item");

this.waitForPopup(/.+/, function() {
    this.capture("parent_window.jpg");
});

this.withPopup(/.+/, function()
{
    // Delay for testing
    this.wait(2000);
    this.evaluate(function(cookie){
        window.document.cookie = cookie;
    }, cookie);
    this.wait(100); // little time to actually change the cookie
    this.reload();
    this.wait(2000, function(){  // only necessary if page is built with JS
        this.capture("new_window.jpg");
    });
});
```

I don't think there is an easier method, if the child window didn't already pick up the cookie. Maybe a bug report for casperjs is in order.

---

The problem may be that you capture the screenshot to early. `wait` is a step asynchronous step function whereas `capture` is synchronous. By calling `wait` before `capture` means that `wait` is executed *after* `capture`.

```
this.wait(2000, function(){
    this.capture("new_window.jpg");
});
```

Comment: Upon further inspection, the cookies are actually there in the child window without doing anything. Any idea why the site would think it's not logged in in the child window?